# How set External Webcam as a default webcam?

Tags: 12.04, command-line

I have HP 18 AIO Desktop, which has inbuilt web cam. How can I set an external Webcam (Logitech C170) as a default cam from command ? Is there any way, Please help me.

Cheese webcam booth or other software can do this but I wan to do it on system based so that it will be work on all webcam related software.

Thanks!

Birendra

Comment: I'm suggesting this duplicate as it *should* do what you're asking. The only downside is if you want to still use the internal one. This won't help there.